# Is It correct to say Let's never surrender

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say "Let's **never** surrender"? Or should we say just "Never surrender"? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Both forms are possible and have names:
The form with "let's" is called hortative, while the bare "never surrender" is called imperative. Imperatives usually omit the subject, which would be some form of "you".

The difference in use is that "let's" is softer, more coaxing, while the bare "never surrender" is very emphatic and commanding.
Here are two references:
[Wikipedia "imperative mood"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood)
[Wikipedia "hortative"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hortative)

A quotation from that second reference under the paragraph "Imperative-Hortative Systems" shows an example with "let's" and without:
  2:  Sing! (imperative)
  3:  Let's sing! (hortative)

Comment: You might want to improve this by explaining the differences between them (e.g. ordering vs asking).

Comment: @Nick012000 Didn't you see the sentence in my answer describing "let's" as coaxing, and "never..." as commanding?

Comment: No, I missed that.